# Continuous bijection between two homotopy equivalent $\Delta$-generated spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

**EDIT**:

1. *First edit after an interesting answer*.
2. *$(S,\mathcal{T}_1)$ and $(S,\mathcal{T}_2)$ are homotopy equivalent to the same Quillen cofibrant space*.

Let $S$ be a set with two topologies $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ such that the identity map induces a continuous map $(S,\mathcal{T}_1)\to (S,\mathcal{T}_2)$ which is also a homotopy equivalence. I suppose these two topological spaces $\Delta$-generated.

> Is it enough to conclude that $\mathcal{T}_1=\mathcal{T}_2$ ?

**Motivation**: I need to prove that some continuous bijection is a homeomorphism. Since the spaces are $\Delta$-generated, it suffices to prove that every continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $(S,\mathcal{T}_2)$ is a continuous map from $[0,1]$ to $(S,\mathcal{T}_1)$. I would like to use in some way the homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Is the given bijection part of a homotopy equivalence or are they unrelated?

Comment: @DavidRoberts In fact in my situation, the continuous bijection is also a homotopy equivalence. I realized that by reading Gabriel's answer.

Comment: Ah, so his example is not applicable then?

Comment: @DavidRoberts You are absolutely right ! I had not realized that either. I'm going to modify my question.

Comment: It's easy to construct a counterexample which is a *weak* homotopy equivalence, where the target space is a Warsaw circle. I don't know if that would be of interest for you

Comment: @DenisNardin Is the Warsaw circle $\Delta$-generated? It seems to me that maps in from an interval shouldn't be able to "see" the interesting part of the topology.

Comment: @TimCampion Ah you're right, I was thinking of compactly generated (which it is, being compact Hausdorff)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X = S^1$ and $X^\delta$ its discretisation.  Then the identity map $\iota: X^\delta \to X$ is a continuous bijection of $\Delta$-generated spaces, although not a homotopy equivalence.  But the map of unreduced cones $$C(\iota): C(X^\delta) \to C(X)$$ is a homotopy equivalence and a continuous bijection, and both spaces are $\Delta$-generated.

Answer (score 1):

[answer is to the original question before edit which posited only the existence of a homotopy equivalence rather than the identity map being a homotopy equivalence]

No. Let $T_2$ be the wedge of countably many circles and $T_1$ be the wedge of countably many circles and an interval.

Comment: A half-open interval?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes a half-open interval. Morally speaking, the idea is to dig a hole by adding open subsets. Anyway, that cannot happen in my situation so this answer is very helpful for me.